# Test class for Organization Fiscal Calendar

Tags: unit-test, fiscal-periods

I have class that using Period like this :

```
 List<Period> thisMonth =[SELECT StartDate, EndDate,FullyQualifiedLabel,Type,Number FROM Period Where type = 'Month' AND StartDate <= TODAY AND EndDate >= TODAY limit 1];
   Date runDate = thisMonth[0].StartDate + 7;
```

This is the snippet that I try to do in test class to cover [Period](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_period.htm).

```
Period period = new Period();
period.StartDate=Date.Today();
period.EndDate=Date.Today()+30;
insert period;
```

It give error saying DML is not allowed on Period.How to create test class on this?

Comment: Here's a [tutorial](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods) to learn how to test Apex. Yes you have to insert periods manually.

Comment: I know how to write the test class but I don't know to cover Period . https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_period.htm , it does not mention that it is insertable.

Comment: have you tried inserting it? maybe with some code in the dev console?

Comment: I update the question.